# Storing User Generated Reports in Postgres DB

Tags: postgresql, database-design

I'm looking for some advice in regards to storing reports generated from data in my Postgresql db. I want to give the user the option to store the output as csv, but I'd also like to be able to save it in the database its. The former is not much of an issue, but with the latter I'm not sure whether it would be better to store the csv file in the database as a binary (bytea) or store the contents in rows. I'm open to suggestions as to what would be the most optimal way of getting this done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say this entirely depends on the requirements you have on how to deal with the "report" in the database and the size limits of the reports.

If you are certain that a report never exceeds 1GB, then you could store the complete report in a `text` column (I wouldn't use `bytea` for text data). So you'd wind up with a simple table:

```
create table report
(
  id integer primary key,
  title text not null,
  created_at timestamp not null,
  content text not null
);
```

Another option is to store each *line* of the report that way you wouldn't be affected by a possible size limit of the entire report (only a limit for a single line)

```
create table report
(
  id integer not null, 
  title text not null
  created_at timestamp not null,
);

create table report_content
(
  report_id integer not null references report,
  line_no integer not null,
  content text not null, 
  primary key (report_id, line_no)
);
```

Comment: Thanks I'll be testing this method